# Jersey Singleton Using Spring: Method cannot be cast to Constructor

Tags: spring, maven, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use Spring to autowire Jersey but I'm getting the weirdest exception as soon as one of the methods gets called.

Here is my resource:

```
package fungle.funfinder.rest.resource;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import fungle.common.hdao.model.ByteId;
import fungle.common.hdao.model.OnError;
import fungle.common.hdao.util.CascadeUtils;
import fungle.common.hdao.util.FetchUtils;
import fungle.funfinder.data.dao.ActivityTypeDAO;
import fungle.funfinder.data.entity.ActivityType;

@Path("activityType")
@Singleton
@Service
public class ActivityTypeResource {

    private ActivityTypeDAO activityTypeDAO;

    public ActivityTypeResource() {

    }

    public ActivityTypeResource(ActivityTypeDAO activityTypeDAO) {
        this.activityTypeDAO=activityTypeDAO;
    }

    public ActivityTypeDAO getActivityTypeDAO() {
        return activityTypeDAO;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setActivityTypeDAO(ActivityTypeDAO activityTypeDAO) {
        this.activityTypeDAO = activityTypeDAO;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(value={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<ActivityType> getAll() {
        Map<ByteId, ActivityType> types = activityTypeDAO.getAll(FetchUtils.always(),OnError.CONTINUE,null,null);
        return new ArrayList<>(types.values());
    }

    @POST
    public Response post(ActivityType activityType,@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        ActivityType existing = activityTypeDAO.getByName(activityType.getName());
        if (existing==null) {
            activityTypeDAO.save(activityType, CascadeUtils.always(), OnError.ATTEMPT_UNDO);
            existing = activityTypeDAO.getByName(activityType.getName());
            if (existing !=null) {
                // success
                URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(existing.getName()).build();
                return Response.created(uri).build();
            } else {
                // failed to save.
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }
        } else {
            // already exists.
            return Response.notModified("An activity type with that name already exists.").entity(existing).build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public ActivityType getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        ActivityType existing = activityTypeDAO.getByName(name);
        return existing;
    }
}
```

Here is my maven dependency:tree:

```
[INFO] fungle:fungle.funfinder.data:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- fungle:fungle.common.core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- fungle:fungle.common.hdao:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- java3d:vecmath:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-geometry:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.geotools:gt-api:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:11.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:20040117.000000:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:cloudera-jets3t:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.94.6-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib:high-scale-lib:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:20041127.091804:compile (version managed from 1.4)
[INFO]    +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile (version managed from 4.1.3)
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO]    +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO]    +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.jamon:jamon-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.0a:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

I am not sure if this is relevant or not, but I was having some jersey jar conflicts a while back, my hadoop jars were pulling in some jersey artifacts so I threw some exclusions in my pom as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jersey-test-framework-grizzly2
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>
                    com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework
                </groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

So when I run my web app, everything seems to be fine until that resource is called when my jsp page loads.  Here is the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey] in context with path [/fungle.funfinder.web] threw exception [A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Constructor
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of fungle.funfinder.rest.resource.ActivityTypeResource errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on fungle.funfinder.rest.resource.ActivityTypeResource
] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.Constructor
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.createSpringDependencyDescriptor(AutowiredInjectResolver.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.getBeanFromSpringContext(AutowiredInjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.AutowiredInjectResolver.resolve(AutowiredInjectResolver.java:92)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:244)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2151)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:641)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1025)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I can also post any of my app contexts and/or web xml file, it's just that this post is already pretty long and I think this might be a classpath issue.  Let me know if you want to see those.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

==================================

Edit: I just moved the autowired to the constructor and now it is working without exception.  Still, I might need to use a setter method in the future for various reasons.  Would somebody please tell me why it fails when I autowire the setter?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a bug in Jersey ([JERSEY-2681](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2681)).  This bug was fixed in [Jersey 2.16](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/release-notes/2.16.html), which was released in 2015.  It was fixed in Jersey GitHub [pull request #115](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/115).

The best fix therefore would be to update to Jersey 2.16 or later.

The issue was that the Jersey code re-implements some of the Spring autowiring logic, but was missing the setter method case. The exception thrown in the `AutowiredInjectResolver` class was because method autowiring case wasn't being taken into account; if the autowired element wasn't a field, the code was assuming it's a constructor. So in the case of an autowired method, a `ClassCastException` was thrown.

```java
private DependencyDescriptor createSpringDependencyDescriptor(final Injectee injectee) {
    AnnotatedElement annotatedElement = injectee.getParent();
    if (annotatedElement.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Field.class)) {
        return new DependencyDescriptor((Field) annotatedElement,
                !injectee.isOptional());
    } else {
        return new DependencyDescriptor(
                new MethodParameter((Constructor) annotatedElement, injectee.getPosition()), !injectee.isOptional());
    }
}
```

If your code is stuck on an older version of Jersey and you don't want to use constructor injection, field injection does still work. So you could annotate the field with `@Autowired` and everything should work. You could still keep the setter around if you still want or need it.

```java
@Autowired
private ActivityTypeDAO activityTypeDAO;

public void setActivityTypeDAO(ActivityTypeDAO activityTypeDAO) {
    this.activityTypeDAO = activityTypeDAO;
}
```

Comment: interesting, I guess I will autowire the field instead of the setter if I ever want something to be optional.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this has since been reported to the Jersey 2 project, and is in their issue tracker backlog: [JERSEY-2681](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2681)

Comment: The bug was fixed in the 2015 release of Jersey 2.16.  I updated the answer accordingly.